# How to get the absolute path?

Tags: python, scripting, file-browser

Is it possible to force uncheck with python the "Relative Path" checkbox in the filebrowser?

Comment: What do you mean by "force" uncheck? Do you want to write a script that does that?

Comment: Yes with python. Sorry. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: May be easier after the fact _`File > External Data > Make All Paths Absolute`_  Than resetting the default of operators such as `bpy.ops.image.open(relative_path=False)`

Answer (score 2):

You need not reinvent the wheel, you can use functions from menu *File* -> *External data* -> *make all 
 paths relative (absolute)*. The python code of this comands are:

```
bpy.ops.file.make_paths_relative()

bpy.ops.file.make_paths_absolute()
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well, however using this command causes an error when installing.

Comment: Accidental relative path when picking a file breaks Python's Pathlib module handling (especially if it is run as a callback) if your prop is a an actual file path chooser therefor this answer is totally useless. It does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure that the path is absolute(which was what I needed to know back in the day) this way:

```
    import bpy, os
    path = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.filepath
    path = (os.path.realpath(bpy.path.abspath(path)))
```